# Python: Name and 'Content' of variable needed in same function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The variables in `Queries` contain each contain an SQL-Query. For example `DF_Articles = 'Select * from Article_Master'`. For this reason the `pd.read_sql_query` part of my function works.

What doesn't work: I want to create and store CSV-files named after the Query, each containing the content of the query.

But when I try to store them (i.e.`Query_csv.to_csv('SQL_data/{}.csv'.format(Query))`) then the variable `Query` contains the whole SQL query and not just the name (i.e.`DF_Articles`).
Is there a workaround for this or do I just not see the obvious thing?

```
Queries = [DF_TripHeader, DF_Articles]

def get_data_from_sql():
if not os.path.exists('SQL_data'):
    os.makedirs('SQL_data')

for Query in Queries:
    if not os.path.exists('SQL_data/{}.csv'.format(Query)):
        Query_DF = pd.read_sql_query(Query,Conn_SQL)
        Query_DF.to_csv('SQL_data/{}.csv'.format(Query))
    else:
        print('Already downloaded {}'.format(Query))

get_data_from_sql()
```

EDIT: changed according to handras and doctorlove's input. it works now!

```
Queries = {"DF_TripHeader":DF_TripHeader,"DF_Articles":DF_Articles}

def get_data_from_sql():
if not os.path.exists('SQL_data'):
    os.makedirs('SQL_data')

for name, Query in Queries.items():
    if not os.path.exists('SQL_data/{}.csv'.format(name)):
        Query_csv = pd.read_sql_query(Query,Conn_SQL)
        Query_csv.to_csv('SQL_data/{}.csv'.format(name))
    else:
        print('Already downloaded {}'.format(name))

get_data_from_sql()`
```

Comment: You probably want `for name, Query in Queries.items():` in your edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the collector variable a dictionary.

```
Queries = {"DF_TripHeader" : DF_TripHeader, "DF_Articles" : DF_Articles}
```

Now you can iterate over this like:

```
for name, query in Queries.items():
    ...
```

If you feel that declaring the query and then storing in the dictionary is redundant, you can do it in one step.

```
Queries = {
    "DF_TripHeader" : "Select * from TripHeader",
    "DF_Articles"   : "Select * from Article_Master"
}
```

Comment: Ran the code (see in Edit), like you suggested.
But got a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`
The problem is that i'll be running around 10 SQL queries in the end and some of them are like 50-100 lines of code, so doing it in one step is not really an option.

Comment: I think the edit is probably another question, to be fair. The whitespace in it look a bit confusing - is this correct? Which line gives the error?

Comment: `for name, Query in Queries.items():`?